# What are the best options for programatically creating an Azure Storage Account with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

What are the best options for programatically creating an Azure Storage Account with Javascript? I've found Javascript libraries that allow you to manage Blob storage etc. once a Storage Account is created, however they do not seem to enable creating a Storage Account itself.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You can either use Portal, PowerShell or Azure CLI. If all you are looking for separate storage location, you can always create a new container and store there. It allows dynamism and you can always use role based security to control access to it. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks you, that answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not create a storage account with javascript. The offical document has explained in the [**Getting started**](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/javascript/azure-storage-blob/12.1.0/index.html#getting-started). And `@azure/storage-blob` is used to consume Microsoft Azure Storage Blob service.

> Prerequisites: You must have an Azure subscription and a Storage
> Account to use this package. If you are using this package in a
> Node.js application, then Node.js version 8.0.0 or higher is required.

As r2018 said in the comment, you can either use Portal, PowerShell or Azure CLI to create it, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-create?tabs=azure-portal).